# Does deallocation imply destruction?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, allocator

More specificly, in C++, does `std::allocator_traits<T>::deallocate` imply `std::allocator_traits<T>::destroy`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to remember to call `destroy()` yourself.  The allocator doesn't know which objects have been constructed and which have merely been allocated.

For example, in a vector, objects 0 through `v.capacity()-1` have been allocated, but only objects 0 through `v.size()-1` have been constructed.